# RxJs - Combine multiple http request results to a single object

Tags: arrays, http, object, rxjs

This is my first assistant call, so pls excuse me if I get some protocols wrong.
I can't seem to get this right.
I'm trying to loop over an array of urls get the result and add the result as a value to
a named property inside the obj results

```
urls = [
  {name: p10, url: 'someUrl_10'},
  {name: p20, url: 'someUrl_20'},
  {name: p30, url: 'someUrl_30'}
];

const obj1 = this.http.get<any>(urls.url[0]) {
  .pipe(
    map(x => ({
      urls[0].name : x.results
    }))
  )

const obj2 = this.http.get<any>(urls.url[1]) {
  .pipe(
    map(x => ({
      urls[1].name : x.results
    }))
  )
const obj3 = this.http.get<any>(urls.url[2]) {
  .pipe(
    map(x => ({
      urls[2].name : x.results
    }))
  )

....
```

I made the calls simple as possible, but a loop will need to be implemented
How would I go from here to resolve the above to?

```
results: [
  {p10: [http.results]},
  {p20: [http.results]},
  {p30: [http.results]}
]
```

Any input will be greatly appreciated.
Thnx

Tried to solve this but wasn't successful

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) to create an observable that emits an object when all source observables receive a value.

If you're hard-coding the property names, it's simple as:

```js
results = forkJoin({
   p10: this.http.get('someUrl_10').pipe(map(({results}) => results)),
   p20: this.http.get('someUrl_20').pipe(map(({results}) => results)),
   p30: this.http.get('someUrl_30').pipe(map(({results}) => results)),
});
```

---

If you need to build the object dynamically from your array of url/names, you can [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) your array to an object keyed by the `name` property with a value of the http observable. Then pass that object to `forkJoin`:

```js
private requestObj = urls.reduce(
  (obj, {name, url}) => ({
    ...obj,
    [name]: this.http.get(url).pipe(map(({results}) => results))
  }),
  {}
);

results = forkJoin(requestObj)
```